# How to check for "statistical significance" of categorical feature in black box models

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, boosting

Let's say we have a categorical feature $X_i$ and we have build a black-box classification model like xgboost with $X_i$ as one of many predictors. We'd like to ask a question: does $X_i$ affects the overall prediction and, if so, how much?

In particular $X_i$ could be:

- a dichotomous variable
- a n-level variable where we are interested in the potential difference between two particular levels

In white-box models like linear regression we have tests to obtain statistical significance. But can we obtain statistical-significance-alike with black box models? Does any tool from explainable artifficial intelligence field is applicable to that? Or would it be better to just perform standard t-test on the output probabilities predictions?

Comment: does xgboost take categorical variables now?

Comment: Well, it's encoded as a standard `int` or `float` variable but with only two values so I guess there's no much difference?

Answer (score 7):

There is a simple, but computationally expensive solution here: permutation tests.

- Evaluate your classifier, with $X_i$ excluded, on your validation data and save the score, $s$.
- Shuffle $X_i$ to produce a surrogate variable $\bar X_i$.
- Fit your classifier with $\bar X_i$ included as a predictor, evaluate it on the validation data to obtain the score  $\hat s$, and the improvement $\bar \delta = \hat s - s$ in out-of-sample accuracy.

  - Repeat this $n$ times to obtain a distribution of $\bar \delta$ values. This is the expected distribution of improvements under the null hypothesis that the predictor is no use.
- Calculate the actual improvement $\delta$ obtained using your original variable, $X_i$.

  - Compare $\delta$ to the distribution of $\bar \delta$ scores. If $\delta$ exceeds the 95th percentile of $\bar \delta$ (or 97.5th percentile for a two-tailed test), you can reject the null hypothesis at $p < .05$.

Comment: +1 for mentioning permutation tests! You can also permute the data on the trained model (this is cheaper to do), but you end up answering different questions. On your example, if there is another variable that has pretty much the same information as $X_i$, then $X_i$ won't be deemed important by the test. In mine, even if there's another variable like that, if the model is picking up signal from $X_i$ then you'll notice it in the test.

Comment: That's an interesting point, thanks. However, am I right in saying that if $X_i$ is a good predictor, and$X_j = X_i + \epsilon$ is already in the model, permuting $X_i$ after fitting will actually decrease performance, since the model should place more weight on $\bar X_i$ than $X_j$? Permuting before fitting allows the model to learn to ignore $\bar X_i$, which seems preferable.

Comment: But then you'll say $X_i$ is not important because you have $X_j$ intact, and when you permute $X_j$ you'll say it's not important, because you have $X_i$ intact :)

Comment: the same happens when you have two collinear predictors in linear regression, and it's perfectly reasonable.

Comment: This is now gone well beyond the scope of the question, but I wasn't convinced by what you've said, so tried some simulations, [results here](https://gist.github.com/EoinTravers/f6665db3bab365f7c11f5846215f504f). It seems that for collinear regression models, permuting the data after fitting the model yields p-values that are too low, while permuting before fitting works correctly.

Comment: @Eoinisonthejobmarket the problem is that you're taking the "true p" to be the (Type-II?) ANOVA derived one, but it's affected in exactly the same way as the permutation p-values: collinearity inflates the p-values, because removing a variable does not reduce the variance of the residuals, since other variables can be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, if we are building a black box model, we do not care the variable importance too much. Because we can have thousands or even million features as input. Models like gradient boosting on trees can automatically select important features.

If you really want to know variable importance (not statistical significance), you may check following links.

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/variable-importance.html

Comment: I though about something more like designing a statistical test on model predictions, for example if predictions differs between groups created by the values of a dichotomous variable.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. (+1) Bending over backwards to get statistical significance for a (black-box) model that was not designed to provide such insight is irrelevant. Variable importance measurements are specifically designed as to encapsulate how a variable influences a model's prediction.

Comment: @Xaume how predictions differ among the levels of a categorical variable in a black box model is not fixed, instead it depends on the combination of the other variables, which may be thousands. In any case those variables will interact with the one variable of interest in an intricate way to yield predictions, too complicate to understand, and that's why they are called black box models. the best you can do is to assess overall variable importance.

Answer (score 0):

## Black-box predictions can be estimated with regression analysis

Suppose that your black-box model is predicting a response variable $y_i$ given the variable $x_i$ and another set of variables $\mathbf{z}_i$.  Denote the unknown prediction function by $g$ and observe that the prediction is:

$$\hat{y}_i = g(x_i, \mathbf{z}_i).$$

For simplicity, let's suppose that the variable of interest is a categorical variable with a finite number of states, and denote the allowable states as $x_i = 1,...,m$.  Then we are effectively estimating a set of $n$ functions $g_1,...,g_m$ that apply for each of the allowable values of the variable of interest.  Writing $g_k(\mathbf{z}_i) \equiv g(k, \mathbf{z}_i)$ and using these functions we can write our black-box model as:

$$\hat{y}_i = g_{x_i}(\mathbf{z}_i).$$

Now, although the form of the functions $g_1,...,g_m$ is unknown (since the model is a black-box), we can generate as many predictions as we want.  Thus, we can estimate each of these functions by standard regression methods, with any number of data points we wish to generate.  The standard approach here would be to stipulate a broad functional form for the function $g$ with a number of unknown parameters, and with interaction terms for $x_i$ and each variable in $\mathbf{z}_i$.  Then you would generate predictions to use as data, and use this to estimate the parameters using standard regression methods, which gives you a regression estimate of the function $g$.  Since you can generate as many predictions as you want, this is effectively a regression problem with an unlimited amount of data.

Once you have estimated the functions $g$, you can apply standard statistical tests for whether or not the categorical variable $x_i$ actually has any effect in the function.  Ordinarily you would compare a regression model with this variable in it to an equivalent nested model with the variable excluded and do a comparison with a likelihood-ratio test.  Ultimately you will obtain a statistical test for the effect of the variable $x_i$ in the prediciton method, along with an estimate of the prediction function.  If you generate a very large number of predictions then you should be able to get quite a good estimate of the function.

Comment: "*... compare a regression model with this variable in it to an equivalent nested model with the variable excluded and do a comparison with a likelihood-ratio test.*" This is practically how a permutation importance would work; just instead of excluding a feature $x_i$, it would permute it and report differences in terms of the metric of choice (Gini, entropy, fit, # of times used in split, etc. etc.)

Comment: this is unnecessarily complicate, ineffective, and distorts the meaning of hypothesis testing. also the form of $g$ may be unclear, but the function itself is not unknown, it's just very complicate.

Comment: It doesn't matter if $g$ is known but complicated.  The idea of using regression is that you would approximate it by a function with a simpler form (e.g., a polynomial).

Comment: then you don't need $g$ at all, you can fit it on data

Comment: The goal is to measure how the black-box predictor $g$ is affected by a particular variable.  So you certainly need $g$.

Comment: you are not measuring how a particular variable affects $g$, you are measuring how it affects a linear model approximating $g$. for what is worth you can fit it on the data directly, because $g$ is discarded anyway. at least, fitting the model on data, you can do proper hypothesis testing.

Comment: I'm afraid what you are suggesting is unclear.  It is unclear what hypothesis you propose to test, and how that relates to the black-box predictor.